Understanding Detecting Duplicate Behavior in Apex Queueable Jobs
In the Apex documentation on Detecting Duplicate Queueable Jobs, it mentions that attempting to enqueue more than one Queueable job with the same signature results in a DuplicateMessageException. However, based on my experience, this exception only seems to occur when a previous job with the same DuplicateSignature is in the Queued status.
My Question:
Is this behavior expected? Specifically, I would like to understand if the DuplicateMessageException should be thrown only when a previous job with the same signature is still in the "Queued" status, or if it should also occur when the job is in other statuses like "Processing". My goal is to use this feature to prevent race conditions by ensuring that only one job with the same signature can be enqueued until the existing job is fully processed.
Demo Code:
public class MyQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        waitThread(1000 * 60);
    }
    
    private static void waitThread(Integer waitMilliseconds) {
        if (waitMilliseconds == null || waitMilliseconds < 0) {
            waitMilliseconds = 0;
        }
        
        Long startTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
        Long finishTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
        
        while ((finishTime - startTime) < waitMilliseconds) {
            finishTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
        }
    }
}

Enqueue Logic:
AsyncOptions options = new AsyncOptions();
options.DuplicateSignature = QueueableDuplicateSignature.Builder()
                                .addId(UserInfo.getUserId())
                                .addString('MyQueueable')
                                .build();
try {
    System.enqueueJob(new MyQueueable(), options);
} catch (DuplicateMessageException ex) {
    // Exception is thrown if there is already an enqueued job with the same signature
    Assert.areEqual('Attempt to enqueue job with duplicate queueable signature',
        ex.getMessage());
}

Any insights or clarifications on this behavior would be greatly appreciated! Is there a way to ensure that a new job is only enqueued after all existing jobs with the same signature have completed?

Salesforce makes no guarantees that even multiple queueables that are in the queued status with the same signature will be deduplicated. If you absolutely need a guarantee, use the FOR UPDATE on a record (either the records being processed, or perhaps a semaphore object as a proxy), in order to ensure order of execution.

Thank you for your response. My question is specifically about why Salesforce released this feature and stated in the Apex documentation that it can help solve race conditions. Given that the DuplicateMessageException might not always trigger, under what circumstances should I use this feature?

@Jair Note it says "reduce", not "eliminate." It does reduce database contention and race conditions by reducing the odds of a duplicate queueable running more than once. You should use it in cases where calling a function more than once would produce identical results, such as queueable operations that may be enqueued more than once in the same transaction due to recursive saves. You should generally use it whenever possible, as it improves performance overall.

Thanks for the clarification. I understand now that this feature is designed primarily to deduplicate queueables within the same transaction, which helps reduce database contention and race conditions, though it doesn’t eliminate them entirely. I look forward to Salesforce providing a more robust solution to fully eliminate race conditions in the future. Currently, using FOR UPDATE has performance drawbacks.
